# Recording RTSP Stream on Event (Pre and Post)

Tags: c#, .net, rtsp

I would like to know how to Read The RTSP Video-only stream (H.264) to a length limited buffer and dump the buffer to file on demand.

The problem is that I have a camera stream and on User trigger it should generate a video which contains frames 10 seconds before and after the event?

How is this possible in .Net C#?

Best regards,

Comment: You already receive H.264 feed over RTSP and you can record it well as well, and the only question is the event thing? Or you wonder how to do this from the ground up?

Comment: The stream is H.264 from camera. I need a way of storing last 20 seconds of the stream in buffer and on event dump the buffer to file.